# HTML/CSS/JavaScript training videos

Tags: javascript, html, css

I searched Google for HTML/CSS/JavaScript training videos but I am not able to decide which one is better. I have subscription of LearnVisualStudio.NET and the videos are value for money. Are there any similar videos for HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: Check W3schools or cssdog this two resources are good for web development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/ offers many screencasts and tutorials for web development, it's worth the try in my opinion.

**Edit:** 
http://www.lynda.com/ seems interesting too, although I didn't test it, I saw pretty good feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend w3schools.com (though they don't provide any video's but it is indeed good for a beginner).

a) [HTML Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

b) [CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

c) [JavaScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

On the top of that, I offers many more tutorials on various topics. Have a look [Full Web Building Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend http://www.w3schools.com/ for basic understanding of html, css and javascript.

Hands on practice on https://www.codecademy.com/.

Some video tutorials on premium site tutsplus.com.